# Upvoting questions/answers of few legends

Tags: discussion, support

Whenever I am free, I will go through answers of few people in  space i am familiar with and space i want to explore.. I will bookmark the question and upvote the answer in gratitude of the amazing knowledge they shared and will then  proceed to next answer of same user.

This process is repeated until I complete all of the answers but very randomly.

So my question is:

Am I/the other user\users in risk of suspicious activity

**Update :**  ( took content from Mike Comment,since i think, i didn't framed it well..)

Theoretically let's say you find a question/answer from someone that you thought was really good. You then go through their history seeing what else they've contributed and you find that the rest of their content is good. So technically it's all associated with one user but really you're voting on the content. Does this get flagged in the system as abusive behavior?

Is this considered abuse..

Comment: Chances are if they are active in a tag you frequently use, you'll eventually legitimately encounter more of their answers over time as you're looking for info about other things without you going out of your way to find their posts.

Comment: It sometimes happens that a user will seek out a posts by another user and either upvote or downvote them all because of a bias for or against that user. That sort of behaviour is not allowed and there are automated processes that try to detect that behaviour and reverse it. What you describe doing is likely to be caught by those processes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're upvoting based on the *user*, not the content of each individual post, that's not allowed. It will be treated as abuse because it *is* abuse.

Don't do this.

To address your edit: The system can't tell whether you're evaluating the information in each post. Moderators do their best, but there's precious little information to go off of. Best case, we don't notice or just warn you; worst case, we suspend you. Either way, nothing *good* will happen.

Comment: Updated question,can you please shed some light on this as well.If this is an abuse,i will stop doing this..

Comment: @TheGameiswar It's abuse, or at least indistinguishable from abuse. Don't vote based on users.

Comment: Theoretically let's say you find a question/answer from someone that you thought was really good. You then go through their history seeing what else they've contributed and you find that the rest of their content is good. So technically it's all associated with one user but really you're voting on the content. Does this get flagged in the system as abusive behavior?

Comment: @MikeC The system is likely to just revert it. If it gets to moderators, we're human, so we do our best to figure out what's actually happening... but there's precious little information we can go off of. Best case we warn you or don't notice; worst case we suspend you. Either way, nothing *good* is going to come of it.

Comment: @undo Cool. Thanks for satisfying my curiosity ;)